# Binary variables state change minimization in MILP

Tags: linear-programming, binary-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have solved and MILP that has binary variables: $b_h \quad \forall h \in\{0, 1, 2, ..n\}$

After solving, an example of the values of $b$ could be :
$$
b=\{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 \}
$$

$b$ represents the states of an engine (on/off) with time. Now I would like to introduce a restriction or extend the objective function in order to **minimize the amount of state changes**.

I though about including in the objective function the following.
$$
f_{min}:\quad abs(b_h - b_{h-1}) \quad \forall h \in\{1, 2, ..n\}
$$

I don't know how to properly linearize this or if there is a better way to do what I described.

Comment: there is a way to linearize $|b_h - b_{h-1}|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $|b_h-b_{h-1}|$ is not an objective function. You may however consider $\displaystyle\sum_{h=1}^{n} |b_h-b_{h-1}|$ as your objective function. Given your current assumptions, we can define the auxiliary continuous variable $y_h$ for each $h\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ which represents the value of $|b_h-b_{h-1}|$ (note that you can also define $y_h$ as a binary variable but sometimes it is not coputationally good to add extra integer variables to your model). We can express your problem as a mixed integer linear program as follows:
\begin{align}
\min & \sum_{h=1}^{n} y_h \\
& b_h-b_{h-1} \le y_h \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall h\in\{1,\dots,n\}\\
& b_{h-1}-b_{h} \le y_h \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall h\in\{1,\dots,n\}\\
& b_h \in \{0,1\} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall h\in\{0,\dots,n\}\\
& y_h \ge 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall h\in\{1,\dots,n\}.\\
\end{align}

If the states are cyclic, then you may define an extra variable $y_{0}$ which represents the value of $|b_n-b_{0}|$. Your model would then be
\begin{align}
\min & \sum_{h=0}^{n} y_h \\
& b_h-b_{h-1} \le y_h \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall h\in\{1,\dots,n\}\\
& b_{h-1}-b_{h} \le y_h \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall h\in\{1,\dots,n\}\\
& b_n-b_{0} \le y_0 \\
& b_{0}-b_{n} \le y_0 \\
& b_h \in \{0,1\} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall h\in\{0,\dots,n\}\\
& y_h \ge 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall h\in\{0,\dots,n\}.\\
\end{align}